# How to annotate all the objects with a new property?

Tags: python, django

```
class Author(Model):
    state = models.CharField('ST')

class Essay(Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField("Author",
        through='EssayAuthor')

>> mylist 
[ <Essay: A1>, <Essay: B4>, <Essay: C9>, <Essay: A3> ... ]
```

mylist is a `QuerySet`.
I want to add another property to each instances of `Essay` in mylist with the `state` of the `Author`(s). It is assumed that the states for books with more than one author are equivalent. Thus for an essay with 2 authors, it doesn't matter which Author is used.

Thus, I want to be able to do this:

```
>> essay0 = mylist[0]
>> essay0.state 
'AK'
```

The `annotate` method is only useful for numeric/float values; so I cannot use that. If I use a generator to inject the property, how can I reconstruct the QuerySet ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you just do this in your model class?

```
class Essay(Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField("Author",
        through='EssayAuthor')

    @property
    def state(self):
        if self.authors.count():
            return self.authors[0].state
        else:
            return null
```

I don't think you can annotate your queryset on the fly in this case, especially with the "use only one author if multiple" logic. Another option would be to use [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to construct a more complex SQL query for this additional data.